# How to use downloaded patch file of android studio again?

Tags: android-studio

I was downloading an update for android studio. After the download was finished, there was some issue and the patch was not applied. Is there a way to use that downloaded file again? I don't want to download again because it will take a lot of time.

PS I'm using ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the “failed to apply patch” Android Studio problem you can follow these steps:

1. Move the Android SDK folder out of the Android Studio folder (quit Android Studio first).
2. Redo the Android Studio update process.
3. Once the update is complete, you will be prompted to enter the new location of the Android SDK.

If these steps do not work for you, update your Java runtime engine (JRE) and development kit (JDK) to the latest version. Alternatively, you could also just download the latest Android Studio build, install it (after renaming the folder of the previous build), and import your projects from the old buggy build.

Comment: I want to know download location. I don't want to download update patches again. Surely android studio use temp location to download patches